# php & MySQL only showing first word

Tags: php, mysql, textbox, echo

I am using PHP to get fields from my database I am using the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_form WHERE id=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   $ProductName = $row['ProductName'];
   $ProductName1 = $row['ProductName1'];
   $ProductName2 = $row['ProductName2'];
   $ProductName3 = $row['ProductName3'];
   $ProductName4 = $row['ProductName4'];
   $ProductName5 = $row['ProductName5'];
   }
```

I then am displaying the filed on the page like this:

```
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'product_name' size='29' value='$ProductName'/>");?>
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'product_name1' size='29' value='$ProductName1'/>");?>
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'product_name2' size='29' value='$ProductName2'/>");?>
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'product_name3' size='29' value='$ProductName3'/>");?>
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'product_name4' size='29' value='$ProductName4'/>");?>
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'product_name5' size='29' value='$ProductName5'/>");?>
```

The problem I am facing is that ProductName & ProductName1 are displaying correctly but ProductName2, ProductName3, ProductName4, ProductName5 is only showing the first word from the database.

However when I view it in phpMyAdmin it is showing more then one word for the field.

I seem to be able to echo and display it on the page but can't echo/display the full field in a text box, it seems to drop everything after a 'space' when displaying it in a text box but it does work when just displaying it on a page not in a text box.

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Copy that query and paste into query block of your phpmyadmin and run. If you get right result. Then problem is in code.

Comment: does that word's contains `'`  or  `"` . better if you post relavant result set from mySQL

Comment: Try this. <?php echo "<input type='text' name = 'product_name' value='htmlspecialchars($ProductName)'/>"; ?>

Comment: htmlspecialchars($ProductName) in the form value

Comment: Instead of wrapping each input in php tags, why not just have the HTML and then use PHP for the value... like so: <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?=$ProductName?> /> --- You could also do a print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result)); to see if you have all the data

Comment: @Vinay - My Query gets a return in phpMyAdmin and my Query displays my field on the page fine, just doesn't load field in my textbox if the item returned has a space.

Comment: @diEcho - data stored doesn't have any ' or " and field names don't have them as well

Comment: @Vinay - Tryied htmlspecialchars but that didn't work

Comment: Vinay. why dont you post what result comes from mysql?

Comment: Try removing `size=29` from the input elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new test.php and paste following code into it and run.

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");   //check mysql login credentials
 mysql_select_db("test",$con);   // change database name here
 $query = "SELECT * from product_form WHERE id = 1;";
 $rs = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
 print_r($row);     // as you are using one record. no need of while loop

 echo "<Input type='text' name = 'product_name' value=".$row[ProductName].">";
 echo "<Input type='text' name = 'product_name1' value=".$row[ProductName1].">";
 echo "<Input type='text' name = 'product_name2' value=".$row[ProductName2].">";
 echo "<Input type='text' name = 'product_name3' value=".$row[ProductName3].">";
 echo "<Input type='text' name = 'product_name4' value=".$row[ProductName4].">";
 echo "<Input type='text' name = 'product_name5' value=".$row[ProductName5].">";
```

Now see what comes as result.

Comment: That worked.. I must have something wrong on my other page, I will check the page and see where I have the mistake.. Thanks heaps